# Conflict Virtual Machine and central repo in bitbucket

Tags: git, virtual-machine, bitbucket, merge-conflict-resolution

I need advice on the best way to solve a merge conflict between a branch in a virtual machine and my central repo in bitbucket.

I want to pull from the repo into my virtual machine branch, but I have a conflict with one file. I want to keep the one in my central repo in bitbucket.

I know there are ways to solve this using tower or kaleidoscope when the merging conflict is between local and central repo, but what do I do to edit the file in the virtual machine and solve the conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Once you get to the conflict part:

```
git checkout --theirs /path/to/file
```

Then check your `git status`: if no other file has a conflict, the merge should be completed.